# A lot of errors during cabal update and finally doesn't work

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, haskell-platform, haskell-stack

first of all thanks for the help you can bring me to solve my disaster with cabal xD...

I'm working with OS X El Capitan 10.11.3, 64 bits.

I installed Haskell platform from https://www.haskell.org/platform/prior.html of 2013.2.0.0, May 2013, specially because i need to work with ghc 7.6.3

Then when I execute cabal update... my headache starts...

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring binary-0.8.2.0...

/var/folders/3l/wflf71t55t92rrvt8lhx_8700000gn/T/10157.c:1:12:
     warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
int foo() {}
           ^
1 warning generated.
Building binary-0.8.2.0...
Preprocessing library binary-0.8.2.0...

src/Data/Binary.hs:198:43:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- This is just a convenience function, it's defined simply as:
                                          ^

src/Data/Binary.hs:253:35:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- This mechanism makes use of GHC's efficient built-in generics
                                  ^
2 warnings generated.

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:110:26:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    PairS x w' = unPut k
                             ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:111:42:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                in PairS (f x) (w `mappend` w')
                                             ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:115:26:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    PairS b w' = unPut k
                             ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:116:38:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                in PairS b (w `mappend` w')
                                         ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:123:22:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                PairS b w' = unPut (k a)
                         ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:124:34:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
            in PairS b (w `mappend` w')
                                     ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:257:64:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- written in host order, host endian form, for the machine you're on.
                                                               ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:286:64:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- written in host order, host endian form, for the machine you're on.
                                                               ^
8 warnings generated.

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:26:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Let's decode binary data representing illustrated here.
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:43:71:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- The fields in @Trade@ are marked as strict (using @!@) since we don't need
                                                                      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:48:12:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Now, let's have a look at a decoder for this format.
           ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:62:20:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
--getTrade' :: 'Get' Trade
                   ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:63:79:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
--getTrade' = Trade '<$>' 'getWord32le' '<*>' 'getWord32le' '<*>' 'getWord16le'
                                                                              ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:70:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Let's first define a function that decodes many @Trade@s.
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:88:27:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
--  input <- BL.readFile \"trades.bin\"
                          ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:235:64:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- The lazy interface consumes a single lazy 'L.ByteString'. It's the easiest
                                                               ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:236:47:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- interface to get started with, but it doesn't support interleaving I\/O and
                                              ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:298:23:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
runGetState g lbs0 pos' = go (runGetIncremental g) lbs0
                      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:300:53:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
      go (Done s pos a) lbs = (a, L.chunk s lbs, pos+pos')
                                                        ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:570:53:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- host order, host endian form, for the machine you're on. On a 64 bit
                                                    ^
12 warnings generated.

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:157:22:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- | Make sure we don't have to pass Nothing to a Partial twice.
                     ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:158:19:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- This way we don't need to pass around an EOF value in the Get monad, it
                  ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:180:63:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
prompt inp kf ks = prompt' kf (\inp' -> ks (inp `B.append` inp'))
                                                              ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:182:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
prompt' :: Decoder a -> (B.ByteString -> Decoder a) -> Decoder a
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:183:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
prompt' kf ks =
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:221:21:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                let (inp', out) = B.splitAt n str
                        ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:222:31:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                in k out (Just inp')
                                  ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:240:17:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
          Left state' -> do
                    ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:241:16:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
            let acc' = inp : acc
                   ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:242:15:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
            prompt'
                  ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:243:40:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
              (runCont (onFail (reverse acc')) B.empty ks)
                                           ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:284:72:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Once it's finished, return the final decoder (always 'Done' or 'Fail'),
                                                                       ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:327:8:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
      let g' = maybe (Left ()) Right <$> g
           ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:328:47:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
      either (const Nothing) Just <$> lookAheadE g'
                                                  ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:403:3:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
     #-}
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:412:64:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
      where -- might look a bit funny, but plays very well with GHC's inliner.
                                                                   ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:413:19:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
            -- GHC won't inline recursive functions, so we make ensureN non-recursive
                      ^
16 warnings and 1 error generated.
Failed to install binary-0.8.2.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-1.22.7.0 depends on binary-0.8.2.0 which failed to install.
binary-0.8.2.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
cabal-install-1.22.8.0 depends on binary-0.8.2.0 which failed to install.
```

and then... I try install binary and...

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring binary-0.8.2.0...

/var/folders/3l/wflf71t55t92rrvt8lhx_8700000gn/T/10204.c:1:12:
     warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
int foo() {}
           ^
1 warning generated.
Building binary-0.8.2.0...
Preprocessing library binary-0.8.2.0...

src/Data/Binary.hs:198:43:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- This is just a convenience function, it's defined simply as:
                                          ^

src/Data/Binary.hs:253:35:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- This mechanism makes use of GHC's efficient built-in generics
                                  ^
2 warnings generated.

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:110:26:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    PairS x w' = unPut k
                             ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:111:42:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                in PairS (f x) (w `mappend` w')
                                             ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:115:26:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                    PairS b w' = unPut k
                             ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:116:38:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                in PairS b (w `mappend` w')
                                         ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:123:22:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                PairS b w' = unPut (k a)
                         ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:124:34:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
            in PairS b (w `mappend` w')
                                     ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:257:64:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- written in host order, host endian form, for the machine you're on.
                                                               ^

src/Data/Binary/Put.hs:286:64:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- written in host order, host endian form, for the machine you're on.
                                                               ^
8 warnings generated.

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:26:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Let's decode binary data representing illustrated here.
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:43:71:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- The fields in @Trade@ are marked as strict (using @!@) since we don't need
                                                                      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:48:12:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Now, let's have a look at a decoder for this format.
           ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:62:20:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
--getTrade' :: 'Get' Trade
                   ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:63:79:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
--getTrade' = Trade '<$>' 'getWord32le' '<*>' 'getWord32le' '<*>' 'getWord16le'
                                                                              ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:70:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Let's first define a function that decodes many @Trade@s.
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:88:27:
     warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
--  input <- BL.readFile \"trades.bin\"
                          ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:235:64:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- The lazy interface consumes a single lazy 'L.ByteString'. It's the easiest
                                                               ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:236:47:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- interface to get started with, but it doesn't support interleaving I\/O and
                                              ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:298:23:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
runGetState g lbs0 pos' = go (runGetIncremental g) lbs0
                      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:300:53:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
      go (Done s pos a) lbs = (a, L.chunk s lbs, pos+pos')
                                                        ^

src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:570:53:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- host order, host endian form, for the machine you're on. On a 64 bit
                                                    ^
12 warnings generated.

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:157:22:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- | Make sure we don't have to pass Nothing to a Partial twice.
                     ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:158:19:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- This way we don't need to pass around an EOF value in the Get monad, it
                  ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:180:63:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
prompt inp kf ks = prompt' kf (\inp' -> ks (inp `B.append` inp'))
                                                              ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:182:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
prompt' :: Decoder a -> (B.ByteString -> Decoder a) -> Decoder a
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:183:7:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
prompt' kf ks =
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:221:21:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                let (inp', out) = B.splitAt n str
                        ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:222:31:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
                in k out (Just inp')
                                  ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:240:17:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
          Left state' -> do
                    ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:241:16:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
            let acc' = inp : acc
                   ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:242:15:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
            prompt'
                  ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:243:40:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
              (runCont (onFail (reverse acc')) B.empty ks)
                                           ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:284:72:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
-- Once it's finished, return the final decoder (always 'Done' or 'Fail'),
                                                                       ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:327:8:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
      let g' = maybe (Left ()) Right <$> g
           ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:328:47:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
      either (const Nothing) Just <$> lookAheadE g'
                                                  ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:403:3:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
     #-}
      ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:412:64:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
      where -- might look a bit funny, but plays very well with GHC's inliner.
                                                                   ^

src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:413:19:
     warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
            -- GHC won't inline recursive functions, so we make ensureN non-recursive
                      ^
16 warnings and 1 error generated.
Failed to install binary-0.8.2.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
binary-0.8.2.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

- my ghc --version is 
  *The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3*
- my cabal --version is 
  *cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
  using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library*

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: The error in `src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs` shows that the upper bound in `binary` on `base` is probably wrong. Any reason why you don't want to use a more recent version of GHC/cabal? Also note that your version of Cabal does not support sandboxes, you probably want to use `cabal-dev` in order to not shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Precisely I want update my library, and use cabal 1.22.7.0 (the current version), I have that version because haskell platform contains by default 1.16.0.2 in my case...

Comment: Remark: `update` is usually annotated with only getting new information (e.g. "update your package list", e.g. `cabal update` or `apt-get update`), since you're getting your lists and info *up* to *date*. Actually changing to a newer version is usually called upgrade nowadays (e.g. `apt-get upgrade`). That being said, you could change to [7.10.3](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) with a newer platform release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a bug in binary-0.8.2.0.

```
src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:403:3:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
     #-}
      ^
```

`src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs` has a line that starts with `#`, which clang's C preprocessor doesn't like. gcc is fine with it, but on a Mac Apple's gcc is really clang.

That line is [new in binary-0.8.0.0](http://hdiff.luite.com/cgit/binary/diff/src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs?id=8a0d0f8ea63278be100bcd7a58c8383542cbabf3), which was released Dec 20. Still odd that apparently no one else encountered this yet.

I filed an [issue](https://github.com/kolmodin/binary/issues/105).

Comment: I can't prove the issue you found... because... 

cabal configure --enable-tests --enable-benchmarks

  Resolving dependencies...
  Configuring binary-0.8.2.0...
  cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
  Cabal ==1.22.*,
  criterion ==1.*,
  tar -any,
  test-framework -any,
  test-framework-quickcheck2 >=0.3

and I dont have, Cabal 1.22... and I cant use the tool for install cabal or update the library, I guess I must download the recent Haskell Platform and then "switch" the version of ghc... what do you think?

PD: I'm a newbie with haskell/cabal >.<

Comment: You already demonstrated it in your original question. I just copied and pasted the actual error from what you posted. I guess that binary has additional dependencies when you configure it with `--enable-tests --enable-benchmarks`.

Comment: This bug has been around for *ages*. I first remember encountering it about three years ago. I think apple had just released a new operating system on which, for the first time, the default `gcc' executable was really a symlink to `clang'. Sometimes it is unfortunate how little library maintainers care about multi platform compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's the result of using an old GHC version with modern clang (which comes with your modern Mac OS X).
GHC uses clang for CPP, and clang is not very understanding about its input.

Newer GHCs don't have this issue, which explains why it hasn't been found and fixed until now.

The [issue was reported](https://github.com/kolmodin/binary/issues/105) on github. I've fixed it and pushed `binary-0.8.2.1`. Run `cabal update` and try again.

[Let me know](https://github.com/kolmodin/binary/issues/new) if you run into any other issues with `binary`.

Comment: Why would newer versions of GHC not have the same issue? Isn't feeding the input to CPP pretty much the first thing that every version of GHC does?

Comment: IIRC GHC stopped relying on clang/gcc for CPP a couple of releases ago. I might not remember correctly though.

Comment: There was a big discussion about that a while ago, but it hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, it can not use the latest version of cabal 1.22.07 with an older version of GHC 7.6.3,because

> It's just a bug in binary-0.8.2.0.

```
src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs:403:3:
 error: invalid preprocessing directive
 #-}
  ^
```

> src/Data/Binary/Get/Internal.hs has a line that starts with #, which clang's C preprocessor doesn't like. gcc is fine with it, but on a Mac Apple's gcc is really clang.
>
> by [Reid Barton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190376/reid-barton)

and important to know...

> GHC uses clang for CPP, and clang is not very understanding about its input.
>   Newer GHCs don't have this issue, which explains why it hasn't been found and fixed until now.
>
> The [issue was reported](https://github.com/kolmodin/binary/issues/105) on github.
>
> by [L. Kolmodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21074/l-kolmodin)

Thanks for every answer.

PD: I could install GHC 7.6.3 and Cabal 1.22.07 using Debian... >.<

Comment: As noted in my comment, try the new binary-0.8.2.1.